# ¿Como evaluar si ya existe un registro en procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado, para guardar o actualizar segun el valor de nOpcion, registro de una tabla de productos..En la misma tengo codigo de barra y codigo alfanumerico y quiero comprobar antes de guardar o actualizar que no se repita, es decir que no se guarden 2 productos con el mismo codigo de barra o alfanumerico:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `USP_Guardar_pr`(IN      
nOpcion int,        
nCodigo_pr int,        
cDescripcion_pr varchar(100),  
cca_pr varchar(100),
ccb_pr varchar(100),
nCodigo_ma int,    
nCodigo_um int,    
nCodigo_ca int,    
nStock_min decimal(10,2),    
nStock_max decimal(10,2),  
nPu_venta decimal(10,2)  
)
BEGIN      
declare xCodigo int ;  
declare fFecha datetime ;   
set fFecha = CURDATE();  
    
if nOpcion=1 THEN -- Nuevo Registro        
begin        
 insert into TB_PRODUCTOS(codigo_barra,codigo_an,descripcion_pr,    
        codigo_ma,    
        codigo_um,    
        codigo_ca,    
        stock_min,    
        stock_max,  
        pu_venta,  
        fecha_crea,    
        fecha_modifica,    
        estado)    
     values(ccb_pr,cca_pr,
     cDescripcion_pr,    
         nCodigo_ma,    
         nCodigo_um,    
         nCodigo_ca,    
         nStock_min,    
         nStock_max,  
   nPu_venta,  
         fFecha,    
         fFecha,    
         1);    
 set xCodigo= @@IDENTITY ;-- obtiene el código que se generó automáticamente    
     
 insert into TB_STOCK_PRODUCTOS(codigo_pr,    
           codigo_al,    
           stock_actual,    
           pu_compra)    
        select xCodigo,    
            codigo_al,    
            0.00,    
            0.00    
        from TB_ALMACENES;    
      
end;        
else -- Actualizar registro        
begin        
 update TB_PRODUCTOS set descripcion_pr=cDescripcion_pr, 
 codigo_barra=ccb_pr,
 codigo_an=cca_pr,
       codigo_ma=nCodigo_ma,    
       codigo_um=nCodigo_um,    
       codigo_ca=nCodigo_ca,    
       stock_min=nStock_min,    
       stock_max=nStock_max,   
    pu_venta=nPu_venta,  
       fecha_modifica=fFecha    
     where codigo_pr=nCodigo_pr;    
    
  insert into TB_STOCK_PRODUCTOS(codigo_pr,    
           codigo_al,    
           stock_actual,    
           pu_compra)    
        select nCodigo_pr,    
            codigo_al,    
            0.00,    
            0.00    
        from TB_ALMACENES     
        where codigo_al not in (select codigo_al from TB_STOCK_PRODUCTOS where codigo_pr=nCodigo_pr) ;   
end; 
END IF;
END
```

O tambien me puede convenir ejecutar otro store procedure previo desde C# y hacer la comprobacion? Trabajo con .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear `unique index` para esos campos y con un error handler atrapar el error de índice duplicado (error 1062).

```
declare exit handler for 1062 return 1;
```

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta para ayudarte a solucionar el problema, marcala con tick así otras personas que se encuentren con este inconveniente puedan encontrar la solución mas rápidamente. :)